# how to iterate through names of lists

Tags: python, list, function, arguments

I have multiple lists (bit0, bit1, bit2, etc), and I want to iterate through them in a loop like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    view_image(bit1[i])  
    view_image(bit2[i]) 
    view_image(bit3[i]) 
    view_image(bit4[i]) 
    view_image(bit5[i])
```

How can I avoid repetition of the view_image statements by constructing the name of its argument inside the loop?

Something like this: `view_image('bit' + str(i+1)[i])`

These lists represent collections of images as numpy arrays. So for example, bit1[0] is the first image in the bit1 collection.

Comment: You can use `locals()` (as in `locals()['bit' + '1']`), but what you really want is actually to put your `bits` in list, dictionary, or class

Comment: @tmrlvi [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.de/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html)

Comment: I completely agree (and it's an handy link). I thought they should know about it anyway (as they study the language) and be discouraged from using it. (Otherwise, they might stumble upon it and use it)

Comment: @tmrlvi I think that is what I was looking for, so would this be something like this: view_image(locals()['bit'+str(i)][0])

Comment: @MichaelSB You really shouldn't use it. It's bad practive. Read glglgl's link to understand why. If you want "dynamic" names, use dictionary.

Comment: @MichaelSB No, not at all. You want to program cleanly, don't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would it do like

```
arrays = (bit1, bit2, bit3, bit4, bit5)

for i in range(3):
    for arr in arrays:
        view_image(arr[i])
```

---

As you are storing several images of different resolution, and have a maybe runtime-determined number, you can resort to the following:

For creation of the list, you can have:

```
resolutions = ('low', 'medium', 'high', 'hq')
images = {} # empty dict
for res in resolutions:
    if pic_present(res):
        images[res] = get_image(res)

# Now you can proceed as above:
for i in range(3):
    for res, img in images.iteritems():
        announce(res, i) # sth. like print "Showing component", i, "of image", res
        view_image(img[i])
```

If the number of images is always the same, you can use a list:

```
images = [] # empty list
for index, res in enumerate(resolutions):
    images[index] = get_image(res)

# Now you can proceed as above:
for i in range(3):
    for index, img in enumerate(images):
        announce(resolutions[index], i) # sth. like print "Showing component", i, "of image", res
        view_image(img[i])
```

The same thing a little bit different, if you have 256 levels of resolution, unnamed. In this case, you just replace

```
resolutions = ('low', 'medium', 'high', 'hq')
```

with

```
resolutions = range(256) # gives you the numbers of 0 to 255 to iterate over
```

and proceed as above. No need to hassle aroung with 256 different variable names, but the data is neatly put into a dict or list and that's it.

Comment: I hoped for a way to do this without constructing the arrays or dictionaries of these names. Can I construct the names on the fly?

Comment: @MichaelSB No clean way, no.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, at the beginning set it up as

```
bit = [[],[],[],[],[]]
```

and build up each part of bit.  Then you can loop through as

```
for i in xrange(3):
    for bitarray in bit:
        view_image(bitarray)
```

If they really can't be put into a list of lists that you can enumerate over, then what glglgl suggested looks best.

Answer (score -2):

This is the answer I was looking for (thanks to tmrlvi):

```
for i in range(3):
    for k in range(16):
        view_image(locals()['bit'+str(k+1)][i])
```

I looked at this blog post:
http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.de/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html
but I still don't understand why this code would be a bad idea in my case. 
If you can explain what can go wrong, I would appreciate it!

Comment: The problem is that it's very hard to follow the code.  You want your code to be readable a year from now, this looks difficult to make sense of 1 week from now.  There needs to be a very good reason why you have variables named `bit0`, `bit1`, `bit2`, etc rather than `bit[0]`, `bit[1]`, etc.

Comment: @Joel, ok, I agree, readability suffers with locals(). Just to be clear, in my case, a name of a collection is bit1, bit2, etc, which reflects the precision of the images in the collection. Each collection has thousands of images. Here I have only 16 different levels of precision, so I guess it's not that hard to put them in the list/dict of names before the loop, but what if I needed to test 1 to 256 bits of precision, and thus 256 collections of images?

Comment: Your case isn't at all different from the other examples in that link. Variable names are essentially for the programmer. In your case, as well as in other cases, it is better to assemble everything under one roof, and cleanly access them in clean programmatical ways, such as dict or list. It is not clear to me why you insist to do it in this quite ugly way when there are much cleaner ways.

Comment: @glglgl Everyone here says it's bad, but only one reason was given: readability suffers. That concern can be addressed with a comment explaining the locals() statement. So, it there any other reason for me to create a potentially huge array of variable names by hand? Aside from readability, is there anything wrong with the code in my answer? What kind of problems can it lead to? The blog post, amazingly, wasted a whole page of text without giving a single reason WHY this is bad.

Comment: @MichaelSB Surely others can explain it better, but it is a very weird way of doing it. I don't know why you are so massively against the other solutions. "Create a potentially huge array of variable names by hand" is what you would have to do with your solution: compare your `bit0 = []; bit1 = []; bit2 = []; ...` vs. a neat loop which adds elements to the dict resp. to the list.

Comment: @glglgl yes, reading my comments 6 years later does make me look silly, doesn't it? I accepted your solution  :)